# Color de texto en input

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Tengo una pregunta:
Estoy programando un sistema que tiene un input que muestra valores numéricos y otro input que indica si el valor es igual o mayor a cero. Cómo puedo hacer para cambiar el color de ese aviso según el valor del primer input? Muchas gracias.

```
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color de Texto</title>

</head>

<body>
    <label for="">Valores Numéricos:</label><input type="text" id="cantidad" onkeyup="valor();">
    <br>
    <label for="">Descripción:</label><input type="text" id="descripcion">
    
</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

javascript:

```
function valor(){

    var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
    var descripcion = document.getElementById("descripcion").value;


    if (cantidad == 0) {
        document.getElementById("descripcion").value = "Igual a Cero";
    } else if (cantidad > 0) {
        document.getElementById("descripcion").value = "mayor a cero";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("descripcion").value = "menor a cero"
    }
}
```

Comment: Para que puedas recibir ayuda es necesario edites y agregues que llevas hecho, de otro modo es seguro termine cerrada, lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar jQuery, obtener el valor del primer input y luego verificar si este es mayor o menor a cero, basado en eso puedes cambiar el color del texto usando ".attr()" para asignar un atributo css a la etiqueta. Por ejemplo:

```js
jQuery("#input1").change(function(){

  // Obtenemos el valor del primer input
  let input1Val = jQuery("input#input1").val();
  
  if ( input1Val > 0 ) { // Si el valor del input es mayor a 0
    
    jQuery("input#input2").val( 'Es mayor a 0' ); // Cambiamos el valor del segundo input
    jQuery("input#input2").attr( 'style', 'color: #3ACB3C;' ); // Asignamos un color al texto con la función "attr"
  
  } else if ( input1Val == 0 ) { // Si el valor del input es Igual a 0
    
    jQuery("input#input2").val( 'Es Igual a 0' );// Cambiamos el valor del segundo input
    jQuery("input#input2").attr( 'style', 'color: #D3DB54;' );  // Asignamos un color al texto con la función "attr"
  
  } else { // En caso de que no se cumplas las dos reglas de arriba entonces el valor es menor a 0

    jQuery("input#input2").val( 'Es menor a 0' );// Cambiamos el valor del segundo input
    jQuery("input#input2").attr( 'style', 'color: #F50707;' );  // Asignamos un color al texto con la función "attr"

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input1" placeholder="Agregar Cantidad">
<input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="Total">
```